# Can I put several different images as channels?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Normally, we set input images 'height','width','channels'.

In 'channels', we set 1 for gray level pictures, and 3 for RGB pictures.

My question is, should it be the same picture using this channels? Like mentioned above.

Or I can set series of images to channels?

(e.g. I have 10 images discrete in space at one moment, so I set channels 10 as one input)

Will there be any problem and is it the right way to do?

Or I should just set 10 input for these 10 images?

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't be the same, because the number of channels of input layer determines the shape of convolutional filters, hence the number of parameters and how they are applied.

Compare these two convolutional networks:

- `[32x32x3]` input shape, `batch_size=5`, `5x5` receptive field, then each neuron in the conv layer will have weights to a `[5x5x3]` region in the input volume, for a total of **`5*5*3 = 75`** weights (and +1 bias parameter).
- `[32x32x15]` input shape, `batch_size=1`, same `5x5` receptive field, then each neuron will have weights to a `[5x5x15]` region, for a total of **`5*5*15 = 325`** weights (and the same +1 bias parameter).

In both cases, the two conv layers sees 15 RGB images, but the second network will use 5 times more parameters to learn the same data, while the first one will reuse the same parameters for different images. Also note that the second network will have dedicated parameters to each first image, each second image, etc.

Obviously, the first approach is better, not only because it saves the resources, it's also invariant to the order of training images in a batch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I can understand what you said and I really appreciate it.

But there are still some questions.

Now, my series of images are "not the same".

Which means I want CNN get features for each image.

My thought is that CNN will get features for each image in each channels.

So I don't need 10 inputs just use 10 channels as 1 input.

Is it correct? or CNN doesn't work that way?

Thanks for answering again!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you confusion, but conv layer uses separate "part" of the filter for each channel, in other words it extracts features from each channel independently.

Comment: So if I want to get the full info for each image, I should set them into different inputs. Setting them into channels can cause info loss. Am I understanding right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're using a mini-batch of images, the conv layer will adapt to each R/G/B channel of all of your images, and extract common features, which is what conv layer is used for. What do you mean by info loss?

Comment: Hmm, it might be my misunderstanding. Let me say again in other way. Assume these 10 images is from A(images are different), and all of them are gray level. There are also 10 grey level images from B. Both A and B from the same class. Then I set A's images to 10 channels and so does B. And make A and B mini-batch. Is it the same that I set 10 inputs for each image to A and B, and make them mini-batch? My Eng might not clearly enough, sorry about that.

Comment: There is clearly some misunderstanding ;) The input to a CNN is one - a single 4D tensor. You increase the number of channels to 10, but it doesn't help the CNN, as explained in the answer. The usual and recommended way to set the batch size to 10 or 20 (as much as your memory allows). I don't see any alternatives to compare this approach to.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I think I found some of my thinking dead zone, lol. I really, really appreciate you, thank you!